# Frida not able to trace sub_XXXXX which must have been called

Tags: ida, android, frida

I have the following pseudocode generated by `IDA Pro decompiler`:

```
__int64 *__usercall sub_155B5@<X0>(__int64 *a1@<X0>, unsigned int a2@<W1>, char **a3@<X8>)
{
  ...
  result = sub_222E0((__int64 *)a3, 2 * a2, 0x20u); 
  return result;
}
```

Using `frida-trace`, I could verify that `sub_155B5` is called for every API request. This is the command that I used:

```
$ frida-trace -U com.app.name -a 'libname.so!0x155b5'
```

Therefore, I thought I could safely assume that `sub_222E0` was also executed, because it's contained by `sub_155B5` which was obviously executed. However, it turned out that I was wrong. `frida-trace` failed to trace `sub_222E0` using the same command above.

What are the possible causes for this outcome?

Thank you.

### EDIT

Here's the declaration of `sub_222E0`:

```
__int64 __fastcall sub_222E0(__int64 a1, __int64 a2, __int64 a3)
{
  return sub_4D2EC(*(_QWORD **)(a1 + 64), a2, a3);
}
```

And `frida-trace` does trace `sub_4D2EC` everytime `sub_155B5` is executed, but not `sub_222E0`.

Comment: I assume this is not full decompiler output. Maybe the code has got "return" instruction somewhere upper, or it throws exception so the sub_222E0 is not executed? Remember the decompiler output is not always correct, thats why you should also pay attention to assembly instructions

Comment: @morsisko thanks for the comment. After some experiment, I found that `sub_222E0` in fact was a thin wrapper function of another subroutine, which `frida` was able to trace. Still confused why this is happening.